# Configuring HSRP but amber ports needed on each link

Tags: hsrp

I'm trying to make an active/standby link for HSRP on TWO 3560 switches. For the standby link, I want amber colored ports for the standby link on each switch, and green ports for the active link. I have two trunk links since I have two uplinks. Here is my output so far for the `show standby` command, but all four ports are green, and I need an amber port on each switch.

```
new#sh standby
Vlan20 - Group 100
  State is Standby
    4 state changes, last state change 01:43:53
  Virtual IP address is 10.10.10.253 (learnt)
  Active virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64
    Local virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64 (v1 default)
  Hello time 3 sec, hold time 10 sec
    Next hello sent in 1.323 secs
  Preemption disabled
  Active router is 10.10.10.252, priority 190 (expires in 9.774 sec)
  Standby router is local
  Priority 100 (default 100)
  IP redundancy name is "hsrp-Vl20-100" (default)
Vlan40 - Group 100
  State is Standby
    4 state changes, last state change 01:43:53
  Virtual IP address is 192.10.10.253 (learnt)
  Active virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64
    Local virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64 (v1 default)
  Hello time 3 sec, hold time 10 sec
    Next hello sent in 0.752 secs
  Preemption disabled
  Active router is 192.10.10.252, priority 189 (expires in 9.187 sec)
  Standby router is local
  Priority 100 (default 100)
  IP redundancy name is "hsrp-Vl40-100" (default)
```

and other switch

```
Switch#sh standby
Vlan20 - Group 100
  State is Active
    5 state changes, last state change 01:45:49
  Virtual IP address is 10.10.10.253
  Active virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64
    Local virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64 (v1 default)
  Hello time 3 sec, hold time 10 sec
    Next hello sent in 1.884 secs
  Preemption enabled
  Active router is local
  Standby router is 10.10.10.254, priority 100 (expires in 7.425 sec)
  Priority 190 (configured 190)
  IP redundancy name is "hsrp-Vl20-100" (default)
Vlan40 - Group 100
  State is Active
    5 state changes, last state change 01:45:50
  Virtual IP address is 192.10.10.253
  Active virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64
    Local virtual MAC address is 0000.0c07.ac64 (v1 default)
  Hello time 3 sec, hold time 10 sec
    Next hello sent in 1.297 secs
  Preemption enabled
  Active router is local
  Standby router is 192.10.10.254, priority 100 (expires in 7.735 sec)
  Priority 189 (configured 189)
  IP redundancy name is "hsrp-Vl40-100" (default)
```

Comment: HSRP is a layer-3 router redundancy technology.  Amber ports indicates a layer-2 spanning tree block.  You are mixing two different technologies.  Your spanning-tree root bridge could be configured to match your HSRP Active router but don't confuse consistency in design with protocol operation.

Comment: could that present amber ports for the link for both switches? how do i configure it to match my HSRP active router with my rootbridge?

Comment: For example set switch 1 to your spanning-tree root bridge and the vlan interface to have the highest HSRP priority.  "spanning-tree vlan ## root primary"  "standby priority 255" "standby preempt"

Comment: Can you please provide a diagram that illustrates what your network currently looks like?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The amber/green lights on the interfaces show whether the port is forwarding traffic or not.  Since that is a layer2 function based on STP, it is completely independent of HSRP, which is a layer 3 feature.

In other words, the state of HSRP has no bearing on whether the ports are forwarding or not.

I can't think of any visual indication on the switch that would show you the state of HSRP.